# Specify directory name with HapiJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I want to include my local CSS/JavaScript file in res.response () of hapiJS. I am not able to load my local file. How can I load my local file in the response of Hapi? How to specify directory name?

```
module.exports = function (req, res) { 
  Router.run(routes, req.url.path , function (Handler) { 
    var content = React.renderToString(React.createElement(Handler, { state: '' }));
    var head = <link href="/css/app.caz.css" rel="stylesheet"/></script> <script src="js/app.caz.js"></script>; 
    var page = ` <!DOCTYPE html> <html> ${head} <body> </body> </html>`; 
    res.response(page); 
  }); 
};
```

Comment: So you want to send a file in response to a request? Look at Inert (https://github.com/hapijs/inert). Specifically the [`reply.file()`](https://github.com/hapijs/inert#replyfilepath-options) method.

Comment: I want to use app.caz.css/app.caz.js file, which is locally stored. Please check the code below:
module.exports = function (req, res) {
    Router.run(routes, req.url.path , function (Handler) {
        var content = React.renderToString(React.createElement(Handler, { state: '' }));
        var head = `<link href="/css/app.caz.css" rel="stylesheet"/></script>
                     <script src="js/app.caz.js"></script>`;
         var page = `
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
         ${head}
         <body>
          </body>
     </html>`;
    res.response(page);
    });
};

Comment: Please add code to your question. It's completely unreadable in a comment.

Comment: Also what is `req` and `res`? These aren't commonly named parameters in hapi. Is your question about express?